# show the element is irreducible in a quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$R=\mathbb{C}[x,y,z,w]/(xw-yz)$
How to show the classes of elements $x,y,z,w$ are irreducible in $R$?
any hint will be helpful

Answer (score 3):

You have taken the quotient of a [graded ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_ring) by a [homogeneous ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_ring#First_properties). It follows that the quotient ring inherits a grading, for which the elements $x, y, z, w$ all (still) have degree 1. Since the non-zero elements of degree zero are all units (complex numbers), you can use this grading to prove $x,y,z,w$ are irreducible. (If you'd like an elaboration or bigger hint, do say.)

Comment: a question: does the graduation need to be defined onto $\mathbb{N}$? I was thinking about $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)$ were obviously we have only polinomial of degree $0,1$

Comment: The gradation need not have non-zero components for every natural number. In the example you gave, the only non-zero grades are $0, 1$, as you suggest.

Comment: I wonder that whether we could prove it by direct verification，because the book where I came across the problem hasnt mentioned so much definition up to now..